# Why use async HTTP request over sync HTTP in a separate thread?

Tags: ios, concurrency, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch

**I know about the difference between how each works but i want to know in a performance wise point of view (resources inside the iphone).**

Lets say I send an asynch request and wait for the delegate to be called. This won't lock my execution thread. But what is the difference of doing this against just sending a synch request in another thread with GCD.

Like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t findPicsQueue;

findPicsQueue = dispatch_queue_create("FindPicsQueue", NULL);


dispatch_async(findPicsQueue, ^{

    NSData *theResponse = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest
                                                        returningResponse:&response
                                                                    error:&error];

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;

    if (error) {
       NSLog(@"Error: %@",error)
    }

    if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) 
    {
        [self parseXMLFile:theResponse]; // Parses Data and modifies picturesFound

        for (PictureData *tmp in picturesFound) {
            NSLog(@"%@",tmp);
        }          
    }  
}
```

It wont lock my interface since its not being executed in the main thread, but it will lock this specific thread. And I also think GCD runs queues concurrently.

Thanks in advance. I really want to clarify this question.

Comment: GCD won't run concurrently on this queue, because you have created a *serial* queue.  For a concurrent queue, you must pass in the DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT argument.  However, it could run in parallel with *other* queues.

Comment: @borrrden if i understand correctly this queue will run concurrently on the device, other blocks or tasks I add to THIS queue will run serially, then again i only have a single block, so it is not relevant. According to the docs: You can create as many serial queues as you need, and each queue operates concurrently with respect to all other queues. In other words, if you create four serial queues, each queue executes only one task at a time but up to four tasks could still execute concurrently, one from each queue.

Comment: @borrrden lol thats not originally what it said! but ok nevermind we mean the same thing.

Comment: @borrrden Not important to original question, but to clarify: iOS doesn't currently support DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT (only Mac OS X 10.7 or greater), so manually created queues are serial. Global queues are concurrent, though. See [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1).

Comment: @RobertRyan Various sources online say that it is supported in iOS 5 as well, and in queue.h it is even marked as available starting from iOS 4.3

Comment: @borrrden Fascinating. Just tested it on a 5.1.1 device and it looks like it supports `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT`. Thanks for pointing this out! I'll probably continue to rely upon global queues for concurrent queue, per the documentation, but it's a curious little feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `NSURLConnection` with `sendAsynchronousRequest`, then almost all processing takes place on the main thread, in particular, the XML parsing will be done on the main thread. Your code example however uses a different thread for processing.

This difference is relevant if you have an iPhone or iPad processor with two cores. Then the XML parsing can run in parallel with some UI activity on the main thread (in your example). So it can be completed earlier compared to running everything on the main thread (`sendAsynchronousRequest` approach).

For older devices with just one core, only one thread will run at a time and the two approaches should behave almost identical.

Comment: The asynch on the main tread doesnt block anything right? which means that its just waiting for the notification to perform the following tasks while executing others meanwhile. The synch on another tread forces that queue to wait which i think it means it behaves as if its constantly running. IF i have 2 processors the main queue is executing the gui things and the other is executing this one but does it count as continuously processing this task until it finishes? how is the concurrency on the second core modified?

Comment: The asynchronous request on the main thread initially won't block anything until the data is ready. The it will have to wait until the main thread is idle (has no UI activity to process) and will then block all UI activity during the XML parsing. So if it takes long, it is relevant. The synchronous request on the separate GCD queue will work more or less continously once it has started. *More or less* because network traffic of course involves waiting for the next network package.